# cucumber.runtime.junit.UndefinedThrowable: The step is undefined

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I have one scenario for two different classes.

My Cucumber structure:

- Test class:

  ```
  @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
  @CucumberOptions(plugin = "pretty", features = "src\\test\\resources\\samuel\\tripleAnd.feature")//and.feature in first case
  public class CucumberTest {

  }
  ```
- Cucumber implementation:

  ```
  public class ElementsTestSteps implements En {

  public ElementsTestSteps() {

      Given("^Element test$", () -> {

      });

      When("^Using element as \"([^\"]*)\"$", (String arg1) -> {
      });

      //Commented on when using the second scenario
      When("^Accept (\\d+) (\\d+)$", (Integer arg1, Integer arg2) -> {
      });

      //Commented on when using the first scenario
      When("^Accept (\\d+) (\\d+)$ (\\d+)$", (Integer arg1, Integer arg2, Integer arg3) -> {
      });

      Then("^Return (\\d+)$", (Integer arg1) -> {
      });
  }

  }
  ```
- When I use the follow `and.feature` feature all work well:

  ```
  Scenario Outline:
  Given Element test
  When Using element as "and"
  And Accept <switchA> <switchB>
  Then Return <resultSign>

  Examples:
    | switchA | switchB | resultSign |
    |       1 |       1 |          1 |
    |       0 |       1 |          0 |
    |       1 |       1 |          1 |
    ...
  ```
- But when I use the following `tripleand.feature` feature I get the `The step is undefined` exception:

  ```
  Scenario Outline:
  Given Element test
  When Using element as "triple_And"
  And Accept <switchA> <switchB> <switchC>
  Then Return <resultSign>

  Examples:
    | switchA | switchB | switchC | resultSign |
    |       1 |       1 |       1 |          1 |
    |       0 |       1 |       1 |          0 |
    |       1 |       0 |       1 |          0 |
    ...
  ```

## Why is everything going well in the first case but not the second?

Comment: The regex of your step definition with 3 parameters has an errant `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple problem in your below step definition function. You got an extra **$** sign after second **(\\d+)**.

```
When("^Accept (\\\d+) (\\\d+)$ (\\\d+)$", (Integer arg1, Integer arg2, Integer arg3) -> {
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second accept regexp is wrong.  You have $ symbol appearing twice in that expression. $ means end of line EOL.  Remove the first $ and it should work fine.  Looks like a simple copy paste error.